# Snowflake External Table creation returns invalid property 'auto_refresh' for 'different storage type from cloud provider'

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, external-tables

I'm receiving this error ***invalid property 'auto_refresh' for 'different storage type from cloud provider'*** when creating an external table after following the guidelines in this snowflake doc [Refreshing External Tables Automatically for Azure Blob Storage](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/tables-external-azure.html)
. Anyone has encountered this before? Any ideas on how to solve it? Thanks in advance

Comment: Please can you update your question with the create statements for the various Snowflake objects you've created - mask any confidential information

Comment: It would also be helpful to clarify whether your Snowflake account exists on Azure, as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that a notification channel is not set.

Run Show external tables and check the notification channel column

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the cloud that is being used, I'll just add what I ran into with GCP backed snowflake instance in hopes that it'll help someone down the line. We allow: AWS, Azure, and GCP. Our standard external table creation properties looks like the following:

```
...
partition by (key1,key2,key3)
with location = @some_stage/key1=x/key2=y/key3=z
refresh_on_create = true
auto_refresh = true
file_format = (type = 'PARQUET')
pattern = '.*.parquet.gz';
```

Our first GCP table was attempted to be created with these, however we received the error mentioned in the question asked. Other instances (aws / azure) did not encounter this issue.

My resolution was to simply set `auto_refresh = false` in our default options. This was after sifting through snowflake official docs on auto_refresh in creating external tables (documentation on auto_refresh [here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-external-table.html)). Since we are handling table refreshes differently and aren't hooking up integration objects or creating triggers - this was an appropriate change.